# How to Remove double quotes

Tags: node.js

**How to remove double quotes from data**

```
[{"label":"Ravi Kanti","data":"[314,444]"},{"label":"Amit prakash","data":"[78]"},{"label":"Roshan Kumar","data":"[215,80,165]"}]
```

As data value is inside double quotes i.e "[314,444]"
How to remove double quotes

Comment: With a regexp ?

Answer (score 1):

Not much to it as that's just embedded JSON:

```
data = [{"label":"Ravi Kanti","data":"[314,444]"},{"label":"Amit prakash","data":"[78]"},{"label":"Roshan Kumar","data":"[215,80,165]"}]

data.forEach(entry => {
  entry.data = JSON.parse(entry.data)
});

JSON.stringify(data)
// [{"label":"Ravi Kanti","data":[314,444]},{"label":"Amit prakash","data":[78]},{"label":"Roshan Kumar","data":[215,80,165]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you can try like this:

```
var str = '[{"label":"Ravi Kanti","data":"[314,444]"},{"label":"Amit prakash","data":"[78]"},{"label":"Roshan Kumar","data":"[215,80,165]"}]';

var arr = JSON.parse(str, function (key, value) {
  if (key === "data") {
    return JSON.parse(value);
  } else {
    return value;
  }
});

console.log(arr);
```